# What was the name of the Arizal's mother?

Tags: names, rabbis, arizal

Can someone please tell me the name of the Arizal's mother, preferably with a source.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the importance of knowing his mother's name?

Comment: To name ones daughter after @tamirevan most Lubavitch families have a Chaya Mushka (wife of the recent Rebbe) most Breslov families have a Feiga after the mother of Rav Nachman

Answer (score 4):

The Geni genalogical website identifies her as **[Lipke Frances](https://www.geni.com/people/Lipke-Luria/6000000029308318281)**. See her other biographical records on [MyHeritage](https://www.myheritage.com/names/lipke_luria).

The last name matches the one of Mordecai Frances which [this biography](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/111878/jewish/Rabbi-Isaac-Luria-The-Ari-Hakodosh.htm) of the Ari identifies as "the rich brother of his mother who took care of his upbringing and education." (similarly [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/isaac-ben-solomon-luria)).